# linux PATH not working

Tags: linux, path

I dont know why rbenv command do not work.. T^T
only work when 'cd /usr/local/.rbenv/bin && ./rbenv'

```
myggul@ubuntu:~$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/java/bin:/usr/local/.rbenv/bin;/home/myggul/bin:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games

myggul@ubuntu:~$ cd /usr/local/.rbenv/bin

myggul@ubuntu:/usr/local/.rbenv/bin$ ll
total 12
drwxrwxr-x 2 myggul myggul 4096 Jul 16 16:11 ./
drwxr-xr-x 7 myggul myggul 4096 Jul 16 16:11 ../
lrwxrwxrwx 1 myggul myggul   16 Jul 16 16:11 rbenv -> ../libexec/rbenv*
-rwxrwxr-x 1 myggul myggul  724 Jul 16 16:11 ruby-local-exec*

myggul@ubuntu:/usr/local/.rbenv/bin$ rbenv
The program 'rbenv' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install rbenv

myggul@ubuntu:/usr/local/.rbenv/bin$ cd ~

myggul@ubuntu:~$ rbenv
The program 'rbenv' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install rbenv
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a semicolon in your PATH which should be a colon.